# Error de diseño a la hora de implementar SwipeRefreshLayout v4 - Pull to refresh

Tags: android

Actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación con un servicio web, y por eso necesita estar siempre actualizada, así que intento aplicar Pull para actualizar

Mi botón flotante desaparece cuando uso SwipeRefreshLayout v4

SwipeRefreshLayout v4

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Y esto es cuando no lo implementé

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Antes :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione correctamente, el `SwipeRefreshLayout` debe tener como hija únicamente a la `RecyclerView`. 
Saca el `FloatingActionButton` de dicho viewgroup.
Si es necesario, crea un viewgroup por encima (con un simple framelayout te bastaría)
Un esquema básico:

```
<framelayout >
    <swiperefreshlayout>
        <recyclerview/>
    </swiperefreshlayout>
    <floatingactionbutton/>
</framelayout >
```

Comment: Muvhas gracias por responder @Corpex, una pregunta ¿como quedaria en mi codigo, creo que lo e puesto mal xq me marca error :c?